# Visio Pie Chart set angle of first slice to 12 o'clock

Tags: charts, pie-chart, visio, angle

I'm trying to start the first slice of a master pie chart object in Visio to the 12 o'clock (0 degrees) position - currently it seems to default to the 3 o'clock position. In excel this would be equivalent to setting "Angle of first slice" property in the Format Data Series group to 0 degrees.

Previously I had adjusted the Shape Transformation Angle to 90 deg but that rotates the entire object 90 degrees including any text associated with the shape. I then thought I might be able to add a new shape data property "Prop.FirstSliceAngle" and set the value to 90 but that didn't update the shape at all.

[image: Pie Chart update]

Any visio specific suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Previously I had adjusted the Shape Transformation Angle to 90 deg but that rotates the entire object 90 degrees including any text associated with the shape. I then thought I might be able to add a new shape data property "Prop.FirstSliceAngle" and set the value to 90 but that didn't update the shape at all.

Pie chart shape contain 10 parts you need modify each of them to get the text in the right position…

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for change slices text angles.

```
Sub PieChart_Modify()
Dim PC As Master ' Pie chart master
Dim PCsh As Shape ' ' Pie chart's main shape
Dim ssh As Shape ' Pie chart's slices
Set PC = ActiveDocument.Masters.Item("Pie chart") ' define PC
Set PCsh = PC.Shapes(1) ' define PCsh
For Each ssh In PCsh.Shapes ' iterate slices
    ssh.Cells("TxtAngle").FormulaU = "IF(BITXOR(FlipX,FlipY),-(Sheet.5!Angle+Angle),-Sheet.5!Angle-Angle)"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue isn't with the text but rather how the first segment is placed. Currently it starts at 90 degrees (3 o'clock) and I'd like it to start at 0 degrees (12 o'clock).

Comment: What shape you mean ?